# handleActionWithIdentifier: forLocalNotification: loads the url using Interactive Push Notifications in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios8, apple-push-notifications, openurl

I am currently working with Interactive Push Notifications in ios 8. I am adding one `UIMutableUserNotificationAction` to load the website URL then i am using the following code in the `handleActionWithIdentifier: forLocalNotification: method`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

It loads the url while click on the **button(NotificationAction)** but it brings the Application in Foreground before loading the URL.
Is there any possibility to load the URL without bring the Application to Foreground,after click on the **button(NotificationAction)**. Can anyone tell me how to work out this?

Comment: Here i am setting the 'activationMode' of 'UIMutableUserNotificationAction' to 'UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground'. if am changing it to 'UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground' it works on simulator but not in the device.